# How do I insert a row of buttons with a staggered, scale animation?

Tags: swiftui

I'm attempting to recreate the following animation from the Castro app...

[image: Castro Animation]

(The GIF is slowed down so you can see the effect)

As you can see in the GIF above, you have a row of buttons that appear when the cell is tapped. Each button has a zoom-in and zoom-out effect. The animations are staggered, such that the first button finishes first and the last button finishes last.

#### What I've tried...

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var show: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    show.toggle()
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Button")
            })
            HStack {
                if show {
                    Button(action: {}, label: { Image(systemName: "circle") })
                        .transition(.scale)
                    Button(action: {}, label: { Image(systemName: "circle") })
                        .transition(.scale)
                    Button(action: {}, label: { Image(systemName: "circle") })
                        .transition(.scale)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image: Attempt 1]

As you can see in the image above... Each button does zoom in, but only as the view is removed. Also, I don't know how to stagger the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false
    @State var showArray = Array(repeating: false, count: 3)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: toggleButtons) {
                Text("Button")
            }
            HStack {
                ForEach(showArray.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    self.circleView(for: index)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func circleView(for index: Int) -> some View {
        if show {
            ZStack {
                Image(systemName: "circle")
                    .opacity(.leastNonzeroMagnitude)
                    .animation(nil)
                if showArray[index] {
                    Image(systemName: "circle")
                        .transition(.scale)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func toggleButtons() {
        showArray.indices.forEach { index in
            withAnimation {
                self.show = true
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(index)) {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showArray[index].toggle()
                    if index == self.showArray.count - 1, self.showArray[index] == false {
                        self.show = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It uses a little *hack* to align the views correctly - in `ZStack` there is a *fake* `Image` with almost no opacity.